# Passing multiple store-data to Ember Component

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I am trying to pass a second model to a component. I have several books that are ordered by categories. The categories are chosen by a Multi-Select-Box and I need to pass the categories (which are stored in my db) to the component. I dont need to change the categories I just need an array. Where and how do I request them and pass them on, if i dont want to inject the store into the component? (There is no way to build a many-to-many relationship, the books only have a string-array for the categories).

Right now I am trying to do this:

books/route.js

```
model() {
  this.store.findAll('book');
}

afterModel() {
  this.set('categories', this.store.findAll('category');
}
```

books/template.hbs

```
{{#each books as |book|}}
  {{book-details book=book categories=categories}}
{{/each}}
```

components/book-detail/template.hbs

```
<h2>{{book.title}}</h2>
{{#each categories as |category|}}
  <p>{{category.name}}</p>
{{/each}}
```

It doesn't work for the categories like this, so I need to find a way to get them from the store and pass them on to my component.

Comment: components don't have models, they only have properties. If you have two models in your route you can pass the second one the same way as you did with the first one. But without code it's hard to guess what you're actually doing.

Comment: You need to set the categories on the controller not the route. ```setupController(controller) {
  this._super(...arguments);
  this.store.findAll('category', (categories) => { controller.set('categories' })
}```

Answer (score 1):

If it's not necessary for you to fetch categories `afterModel`, I recommend considering this approach and dropping your afterModel implementation.

```
model() {
  return {
    books: this.store.findAll('book'),
    categories: this.store.findAll('category')
  }
}
```

Personally, I've moved towards defining a route's model only if there's a single model associated with the route in question (i.e. `/books/thug-kitchen`). In the case where I have multiple models that apply for a given route I favor using properties.

Answer (score 0):

A better approach would be to use `Ember.RSVP.hash`, as follows:

```
model: function() {
  return Ember.RSVP.hash({
    books: this.store.findAll('book'),
    categories: this.store.findAll('category')
  });
},

setupController: function(controller, models) {
  controller.setProperties(models);
}
```

This code will work most correctly if the response from the server is delayed. Tyler's approach works, but the transition to the route happens too soon, before the find is complete. I think his approach works because you're using Ember Data, but it doesn't work if it's a more generic Promise. I wish I could explain better, but my own understanding is still very basic.

After that you shouldn't have any problem passing both models on to the component.